# Youtube Upload JS with API -> get 405 Method not allowed

Tags: javascript, youtube

I can't upload videos to youTube with Javascript anymore. If I call the URL

```
$.ajax({
                url: VIDEOS_UPLOAD_SERVICE_URL,
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                    'x-upload-content-length': file.size,
                    'x-upload-content-type': file.type
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(metadata)
            }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
...DO SOMETHING
}
})
```

I get an Error 405 Method not allowed, but a few days/weeks ago everything works fine :-(

The VIDEOS_UPLOAD_SERVICE_URL is https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet

But if I call the ajax Request to fetch the categories that works fine...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am using a different API but still going to the YouTube service URL and am getting the same error.